# How to show one element on mouse-enter - Angular 4+

Tags: angular, typescript, mouseevent, mouseenter

I have a form which needs to show a cancel icon on mouse enter to the relevant element. But on mouse enter , all the cancel icons are visible. I have referred similar questions but those didn't solve my issue.
Here are the code segments

.html

```
 <div *ngFor='let tool of dropzone; let i=index' (mouseenter)="showIcon(i)" (mouseleave)="hideIcon(i)">
            <label>{{tool}}  </label></td>          
            <mat-icon (click)="cancel(tool,i)">
              <div *ngIf="isHovering">cancel </div>            
            </mat-icon>
 </div>
```

component.ts

```
showIcon(tool) {
    this.isHovering = true;
    console.log(tool)
  }
  hideIcon() {
    this.isHovering = false;
  }
```

How can i display only the relevant element's cancel icon on mouse enter?

Comment: What is dropzone ? Is it an array of objects? Or a simple array ? Can tyou plz create a fiddle of your issue

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma yes it is an array of strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Issue

The issue is with the `isHovering`. You are using the same variable for all.

### Solution

If you don't want to touch the existing variable `dropzone` then you can create separate object to hold the status of each icons. Refer the below implementation

### ts

```
iconsState = { };

showIcon(index) {
    this.iconsState[index] = true;
  }
  hideIcon() {
    this.iconsState[index] = false;
  }
```

### html

```
    <div *ngFor='let tool of dropzone; let i=index' (mouseenter)="showIcon(i)" (mouseleave)="hideIcon(i)">
                    <label>{{tool}}  </label></td>          
                    <mat-icon (click)="cancel(tool,i)">
                      <div *ngIf="iconsState[i]">cancel </div>            
                    </mat-icon>
   </div>
```

Comment: Changed `iconsState[index]` to `iconsState[i]` in html.

Answer (score 0):

you can have unique isHovering state for each div like this

html

```
 <div *ngFor='let tool of dropzone; let i=index' (mouseenter)="showIcon(i)" (mouseleave)="hideIcon(i)">
                <label>{{tool}}  </label></td>          
                <mat-icon (click)="cancel(tool,i)">
                  <div *ngIf="tool.isHovering">cancel </div>            
                </mat-icon>
     </div>
```

component.ts

```
 showIcon(index:number) {
        if(index>=0){
           this.dropzone[index].isHovering=true
        }
      }
      hideIcon(index:number) {
        if(index>=0){
           this.dropzone[index].isHovering=false;
        }
      }
```

Comment: you need to add IsHovering attribute in the dropzone model for this solution to work